# Jenkins Xcode Plugin v 2.0.0 weird behavior

Tags: xcode, jenkins, xcode-plugin

In "**General build settings**" of Jenkins Xcode Plugin version **2.0.0**, I have not checked the box against "**Generate Archive?**" field, but when I run the build job it takes "**archive:YES**" always.

Log as below:-

Going to invoke xcodebuild:target: SDKIntegrationProj, sdk: iphoneos10.3, project: SDKIntegrationProj.xcodeproj, configuration: Release, clean: NO, archive:YES, symRoot: DEFAULT, buildDir: DEFAULT, developmentTeamID: <########>

Due to this it results in error as below:-

xcodebuild: error: The flag -scheme is required when specifying -archivePath but not -exportArchive.
Build step 'Xcode' marked build as failure

I tried checking the box against "Generate Archive?" field[image]and then un-checking it and re-run it. It still results the same error.

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Sadly no. Looks like I hit dead head.

Comment: It appears that you have to configure the -scheme somewhere else, but I'm trying to figure this out as well